# Is there an open-source master list of MSA (Metro / Micro Statistical Areas) available in a machine-readable format

Tags: data-request

Is there a freely available master list of MSA (Metropolitan or Micropolitan Statistical Area (USA)) with the codes and their corresponding human-friendly name, one that can be downloaded in a single file in a machine-readable format like CSV or Excel? I haven't found one in an importable format yet.

I have been handed a dataset of locations that have been characterized by a MSA code and I need to write a simple report against it that displays the human-friendly area name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Census Bureau has MSA's outlined in their API system. [Here](https://api.census.gov/data/2019/acs/acs1?get=NAME,B01001_001E&for=metropolitan%20statistical%20area/micropolitan%20statistical%20area:*) is an example of the list of 2019 MSA with total populations. It is technically in JSON format, but it would be very easy to Find/Replace the brackets and end-of-line commas out to turn it into a comma-separated values structure.